# How can i provide DAO class entity but hide it behind an interface?

Tags: android, ormlite

I have a ORMLITE DAO class `User` and `IUser` interface to provide to the client as an API for User.

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = User.TABLE_NAME)
public class User {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "USER";
}
```

When user login I am saving user info in the `USER` table using ormlite. When whenever user request for current `User` I have to return
interface IUser.  How can I give all user details with out expose `User.java` to client?

Comment: I assume that `User` implements `IUser`?

Comment: But in that case All methods what i have to give to client also need to override at User and need to declare those extra methods at IUser. It would be difficult if no of fields in User.java is more.

Comment: I don't understand that.  If you want to return an interface instead of the entity, all of methods that the client needs to call will be in the interface, right?

Comment: Can you step back and explain _why_ you are doing this?  What is the goal?